# If $\log_x y = \log_y x$, what is $xy$?

Tags: logarithms

I have a question that I cannot solve. This mathematical problem has been taken from the book Mathematical Problem written by Faniye Alan and Ahmet Hançerlioğlu.

$$\log_x y =\log_y x $$
$$ x\neq y; x \neq 1; y \neq 1$$

what is x * y?

A)1/2 B)1 C)2 D)10 E)12

**Base Change Rules of Logarithm**

$$\log_x y=\frac{\log_z y}{\log_z x}$$
$$\log_x y=\frac{1}{\log_y x}$$

**My Deduction**
$$\log_x y=\frac{1}{\log_y x}  $$
$$ {\log_y x} =\log_x y $$
$$\log_x y=\frac{1}{\log_x y}  $$
$$ (\log_x y)^2=1  $$

I cannot go further. How can I solve it?

Comment: The only possibility is $\log_xy=-1$. What does that tell you about the relationship between $x$ and $y$

Comment: You have the identity that $\log_x y = \frac 1{\log_y x}$ so you have $\log_y x=\frac 1{\log_y x}$.   How many numbers have the property $M = \frac 1M$?  Well $M = \pm 1$ are the only option.  If $\log_ x y = 1$ then $x^1 = y$ and $x = y$.  That is not so so $\log_x y = -1$ and $x^{-1} = \frac 1x = y$.  This can be any option:  $\log_{2751} \frac {1}{2751} = -1 = \log_{\frac 1{2751}} 2751$ for example so no problem.... And so $xy = \frac 1y \cdot y = 1$.  The answer is $xy = 1$.  Note: no-one every asked you what $x$ or $y$ were, just what the product was.

Comment: thank you fleablood